# Getting array elements using array index in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

Consider following collection in mongoDB :

```
{a:[4,2,8,71,21]}
{a:[24,2,2,1]}
{a:[4,1]}
{a:[4,2,8,21]}
{a:[2,8,71,21]}
{a:[4,2,8]}
```

How can I get following results in a most easily:

Getting nth element of array

```
{a:4}
{a:24}
{a:4}
{a:4}
{a:2}
{a:4}
```

Getting elements 2 to 4

```
{a:[8,71,21]}
{a:[2,1]}
{a:[]}
{a:[8,21]}
{a:[71,21]}
{a:[8]}
```

And other similar queries.

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for is the [`$slice` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/).

#### Getting a number of elements from the beginning of an array

You can pass a simple `$limit` with a number of values to return (eg. 1):

```
> db.mycoll.find({}, {_id: 0, a: { $slice: 1}})
{ "a" : [ 4 ] }
{ "a" : [ 24 ] }
{ "a" : [ 4 ] }
{ "a" : [ 4 ] }
{ "a" : [ 2 ] }
{ "a" : [ 4 ] }
```

#### Getting a range of elements

You can pass an array with parameters of ( `$skip`, `$limit` ).

Note: to match your expected output you would have to find elements 3 to 5 (skip the first 2 elements, return the next 3):

```
> db.mycoll.find({}, {_id: 0, a: { $slice: [2,3]}})

{ "a" : [ 8, 71, 21 ] }
{ "a" : [ 2, 1 ] }
{ "a" : [ ] }
{ "a" : [ 8, 21 ] }
{ "a" : [ 71, 21 ] }
{ "a" : [ 8 ] }
```

#### Getting the nth element of array

Pass the number of elements to $skip and a value of 1 for the limit.

For example, to find the second element you need to skip 1 entry:

```
> db.mycoll.find({}, {_id: 0, a: { $slice: [1,1]}})

{ "a" : [ 2 ] }
{ "a" : [ 2 ] }
{ "a" : [ 1 ] }
{ "a" : [ 2 ] }
{ "a" : [ 8 ] }
{ "a" : [ 2 ] }
```

#### Note that the `$slice` operator:

- always returns an array
- will return an empty array for documents that match the find criteria but return an empty result for the $slice selection (eg. if you ask for the 5th element of an array with only 2 elements)

Comment: Thanks, in case one I want to get scaler value: {'a':'x'} and not {'a':['x']}

Comment: The `$slice` operator always returns an array. I don't believe there is syntax (as at MongoDB 2.2) to project a single simple array element as a scalar. You could achieve this with MapReduce, but that seems like overkill compared to just converting the single element array returned by `$slice` to a scalar in your application code if needed. If your array contained embedded documents and you wanted to match specific values (not an array position) you could use the [`$elemMatch` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) to return the first matching element.